# Excel Macro to sort names and only include names with x occurences

Tags: excel, vba

I need help creating a macro for Excel that counts a column of names. If there's 2 or more occurences of the name, delete the duplicates. If there's less than 2 occurences, delete the name from the list altogether. Can someone help?

For instance, the column:

1. John Smith
2. John Smith
3. Jane Smith
4. Patty Smith
5. Jim Smith
6. Jim Smith
7. Jim Smith

After the macro turns into:

1. John Smith
2. Jim Smith

Comment: -1 For not trying. Show us what you have tried. SO is not a place where you get spoonfed code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this ..

Assumed it's as cell A1 .. You will get the result in column B .. you can delete column C after get the result ..

```
Sub CheckOccurance()
Dim LastA, r As Range
Dim x, x2, Bn As Long
Dim s As String
Dim IsDoub As Boolean

Set LastA = Range("A65536").End(xlUp)
Bn = 1

For x = 1 To LastA.Row
  If Not Cells(x, 3) = "x" Then
    s = Cells(x, 1)
    Cells(x, 3) = "v"
    IsDoub = False
    For x2 = x + 1 To LastA.Row
      If Cells(x2, 1) = s Then
        Cells(x2, 3) = "x"
        IsDoub = True
      End If
    Next
    If IsDoub Then
      Cells(Bn, 2) = s
      Bn = Bn + 1
    End If
  End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This works, thanks so much. Sorry, I'm not a computer programmer :( I just googled for help and this was where i landed.